# spring.config.location not working without classpath resource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have my config class as below

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value= "classpath:conf/agent.properties")
public class AppConfig{
```

While running the application using

```
java -jar app.jar spring.config.location=path-to-external-property-file
```

the application runs fine and takes the properties from the external properties file, but if the properties file in classpath is missing `FileNotFoundException` is thrown, is this expected behavior? For me it should work with the external properties, it should not care about classpath resource and stop running.

To overcome this I am currently using `ignoreResourceNotFound = true`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mis-understand the meaning of `spring-config-location`.
  From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files), by default spring searches for a file named `application.properties` in certain locations in your project(`/config`, ..) to setup application context.
 You can tell spring that you don't want to use this packaged file in the project, and you will specify the file needed to setup application context at run time using command line arguments. This is facilitated using 
`spring-config-location` option.

Having said that, in your project you might have several configuration (`@Configuration`) files. And some files need some properties to be loaded from some file. This can be specified using `@PropertySource`, which is what you are doing. This is not like a replacement for `application.properties`. `@PropertySource` is just an indication to tell spring that it needs to read a file to inject properties specified in a particular class. 
 Hence even if you specify external config location spring before setting up the `AppConfig` class it looks for the Source mentioned in `@PropertySource`

Comment: but it works for other files too, I have file named agent.properties and if I provide an different external path(other than @PropertySource), spring is picking it up from that location, the only problem is, I am getting FileNotFoundException if ignoreResourceNotFound = true is not added

Comment: Yes, as I explained. It doesn't matter if you provide external files or not, if you have PropertySource, then it must be able to find that file

Comment: Ok, so the flow will be, spring will first look for @PropertyResource path and if not found, application will exit with exception, even if we referred external properties. Is that right?

Comment: The order is spring first searches for the file specified from the command line and then searches for `@PropertySource`.

Comment: If Spring first searches for the file specified in command line then I should not have gotten FileNotFoundException, because the file specified in command line exists where as class path file was missing

Comment: okay. so what should happen when spring encounters `@PropertySource`. There might be some properties you define in external file and some properties in the classpath file. And there could be some properties in both. How will spring decide ? hence it searches for all the source files

Comment: In docs it is mentioned that " You can provide default values for you application in application.properties (or whatever other basename you choose with spring.config.name) in one of the default locations. These default values can then be overriden at runtime with a different file located in one of the custom locations", so Spring suggests to maintain files at two locations. But IMHO spring avoid default location if custom location is given